# Is it possible to build Single GCC Executable for armv5, armv6, armv7-{cortex-xx-{A,R,M}},armv8 etc.?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compilation

Digging into the sources of [GCC](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/) I noticed in files gcc/config/arm/t-*, There are multiple arm target options.

Reading [[GCC internal Manual]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Target-Fragment.html), These are called **Target Makefile Fragments**, which will be included in main Makefile, like **MULTILIB_OPTIONS, MULTILIB_DIRNAMES, MULTILIB_MATCHES, MULTILIB_REQUIRED, MULTILIB_REUSE, MULTILIB_EXTRA_OPTS, MULTILIB_OSDIRNAMES, MULTIARCH_DIRNAME.**

What I am not able to understand that how to bring it in at the time of configure.Which option to choose?

More over is it possible to edit those t-* files as per the requirement and how?